# Dynamically call python-class defined in config-file

Tags: python

I have a config.cfg which I parse using the python-module ConfigParser. In one section I want to configure assignments of the form `fileextension : ClassName`. Parsing results in the following dictionary:

```
types = {
  "extension1" : "ClassName1",
  "extension2" : "ClassName2"
}
```

*EDIT: I know I can now do:*

```
class_ = eval(types[extension])
foo = class()
```

*But I was given to understand that `eval` is evil and should not be used.*

**Do you know a nicer way to dynamically configure which file-extension results in which class?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `eval`, if the class name in the config file exactly matches the class names in your python code (and if the classes are in scope!), but ..... eval is *evil* (a coincidence that there's only one letter difference?  I think not!)

---

A safer way to do it would be to add an extra dictionary that maps from configuration class name to python class name.  I'd do this because:

- configuration files don't have to know about your code's names
- can change config files without changing code and vice versa
- it avoids `eval`

So it'd look something like:

```
mappingDict = {"ClassName1" : MyPythonClass1, 
               "ClassName2" : MyPythonClass2, ... }
# keys are strings, values are classes
```

Then you perform a lookup using the value from the config file:

```
myClassName = types['extension1']
myClass = mappingDict[myClassName]
```

Comment: Hi Matt, when ``MyPythonClass1`` is defined in another module, we'll need to import it first, right? Can we avoid that, as importing the class will import all the class' imports, which might be undesirable?

Answer (score 0):

If `module` is the module the class named `classname` lives in, you can get the class object using

```
class_ = getattr(module, classname)
```

(If the class lives in the main module, use `import __main__` to get a module object for this module.)

To look up the class in the current module's global scope, use

```
class_ = globals()[classname]
```

I think a static dictionary as in [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105533/dynamically-call-python-class-defined-in-config-file/8105589#8105589) is the better solution.